# About HLSL array packing policy

Tags: shaders, hlsl, data-structure, memory

This is not a question but a confirmation if I'm correct about the behavior of HLSL arrays.

I'm working with a standard lighting vertex shader, HLSL plus C++, DirectX11.1 API. For storing my lights data I've setup a simple declaration, padded accordingly to match the packing requeriments of constant buffers:

```
  // C++ side   
struct LightBase {
            DirectX::XMFLOAT3   pos, color;
            DirectX::XMFLOAT3   color;
            float               intensity;
            float               isOn;
    };
    struct CBUFFER_LIGHT {
        LightBase   light[MAX_LIGHTS];
        float       numActiveLights;
        float       _padding[3];
    };
```

The shader declares a "matching" cbuffer as:

```
// HLSL vertex shader
    struct LightBase {
        float3 pos;
        float3 color;
        float  intensity;
        float  isOn;
    };
    cbuffer lights : register (b3) {
        LightBase light[MAX_LIGHTS];
        float numActiveLights;
    }
```

Now, as I expected, it didnt work due to the HLSL memory organization policy regarding arrays. e.g; if I set the buffer from C++ with the following data:
[image]
I get the following data when accessing struct members of light[0] from shader:

[image]

See how `light[0].color` and other struct members  got messed up?  Seems that HLSL will organize your arrays in Vector4 elements *regardless of the real type of the array element*.

So the array data passed from C++ which is `{ -7, -1, -100, 0.44, 0.66, 0.88, 1.0, 1.0 }` will be organized by HLSL as follows:

```
A[0] = { -7, -1, -100, 0.44 }
A[1] = { 0.66, 0.88, 1.0, 1.0 }
A[2] = { ...}
```

So `A[0]` contains .xyz for position and .x for color struct member. `A[1]` contains .gb for color member, intensity and isOn data.

But calling `light[0].color` from the shader will still try to address `&light + sizeof(float3)+sizeof(float3)` as defined in the cbuffer, but ***you will get incorrect results due to array organization policy of HLSL*.**

If HLSL and DirectX are so fond of FLOAT4 values, it's not better to use all float4 variables and access members (.xyzw)  as needed? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules are a bit convoluted but the essence is that if a vector element would wrap into the next register, it's put at the beginning of the next register.

Your CPU-side and GPU-side definitions do not agree on actual member offsets, you need to manually pad your type on the CPU side according to the rules if you want to use a struct.

You can achieve a tighter packing by organizing your buffer elements such that they logically group up in chunks of 4.

```
float3 pos; float intensity;
float3 color; float isOn;
```

Encoding things in clunky float4 tends to be reserved for the case when you encode things in multi-component textures:

```
float4 pos3_and_intensity;
float4 color3_and_isOn;
```